# How to Print statement from Dalvik Code to Terminal?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, adb, android-logcat, dalvik

I want to print out the log statements when I modify Dalvik vm JNI.cpp, to check if the app is using certain method of the cpp file. How can I print from Dalvik?

Comment: you don't. as in you do not **print to the terminal**. just keep logging your messages to the log where they belong

Comment: How? Using Logcat?